# How to create a complete mulilanguage site using xili language plugin?

Tags: menus, multi-language

I am using xili language plugin for create a multi language site. Using this i can create posts and pages on different languages. But when i switch to other language the menus doesn't converted to other language. How can i convert the menus too. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to convert the nav menu container can be switched, some the content is switched..

To start see this link in wiki

http://wiki.xiligroup.org/index.php/Xili-language:_navigation_menu

and example child themes (link in readme.txt displayed in plugin pages)